# Method for querystring not returning value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am passing some value from one page to another page via query string, it passes the values correctly and then passes to the stored procedure succesfully but typing the `Request.QueryString["something"]` again and again is very irritating, so I created a method for it, but the method does not return/passes any value and the nullreference exception is thrown.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (Property_dbDataContext context = new Property_dbDataContext())
        {
            _errMsg.Enabled = false;
            _errMsg.Visible = false;                    

            var find_prop = context.find_property(val("city"), val("type"), val("subtype"), val("bedrooms"), val("size_unit"), Convert.ToInt32(val("area_from")), Convert.ToInt32(val("areato")), Convert.ToInt32(val("pricefrom")), Convert.ToInt32(val("priceto"))).ToList();
            //code above does not return any value

            //var find_prop = context.find_property(Request.QueryString["city"], Request.QueryString["type"], Request.QueryString["subtype"], Request.QueryString["bedrooms"], Request.QueryString["size_unit"], Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["area_from"]), Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["areato"]), Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["pricefrom"]), Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["priceto"])).ToList();  
           //code above return value from the database but its a long procedure

            rptr_properties.DataSource = find_prop;
            rptr_properties.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _errMsg.Enabled = true;
        _errMsg.Visible = true;
        _errMsg.Text = "Sorry! Property not found." + ex;
    }
}

public string val(string a)
{
    return Request.QueryString["" + a + ""].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    This will work
    public string val(string a)
    {
        return Request.QueryString[a];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the item exists before trying to access it:

```
public string val(string a)
{
    if(Request.QueryString[a] != null)
       return Request.QueryString[a].ToString();

    return string.Empty;
}
```

In reference to your comment; this in particular:

```
Convert.ToInt32(val("area_from"))
```

Is going to cause a problem because the default value is an empty string.

Something like this should work for now though:

```
public string ValToString(string a)
{
    if(Request.QueryString[a] != null)
       return Request.QueryString[a].ToString();

    return string.Empty;
}

public int ValToInt32(string a)
{
    if(Request.QueryString[a] != null)
       return Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[a]);

    return 0;
}
```

You would then modify your find code:

```
var find_prop = context.find_property(ValToString("city"), ValToString("type"), ValToString("subtype"), ValToString("bedrooms"), ValToString("size_unit"), Convert.ToInt32(val("area_from")), Convert.ToInt32(val("areato")), ValToInt32("pricefrom"), ValToInt32("priceto")).ToList();
```

Comment: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value) at find_properties.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\haide_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Property_site\find_properties.aspx.cs:line 23

Comment: thanks for the suggestions...appreciated alot... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Better method for converting a querystring value to an int(32):

```
public int GetIntFromQueryString(string key)
{
    int result = int.MinValue;
    if(Request.QueryString[key] != null)
    {
        int.TryParse(Request.QueryString[key].ToString(), out result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If TryParse fails to convert the value the method will return 'int.MinValue', you can then check the returned value does not equal 'int.MinValue' and go from there.